# What is the appropriate method to create this icon layout in CSS?

Tags: html, css

See the photo icons below:

[image]

If I'm just using vanilla HTML/CSS (no frameworks etc.), would the best way to create these overlapping icons be to use flexbox with negative margin-left for each img?

Or just use inline-block for each image and give negative margins to each one?

Comment: Show us what you tried and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Without seeing the structure of your HTML this question cannot be answered fully. What would you want to happen if too many photos are added to fit on one line on a small viewport? The answer to this might help decide what is an 'appropriate' solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods seem to work correctly, there is no rule to it. I personally prefer to use flex.

```css
.user-overlap {
  display: flex;
}
.users-overlap img:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.users-overlap img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="users-overlap">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" height="60" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" height="60" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" height="60" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4" height="60" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The method I would recommend would be using flexbox as you suggested because it will give you more flexibility to adjust the layout easily in the future if needed. Here's the snippet to show how I would approach the image overlay using simple HTML/CSS:

```css
.profile-image__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.profile-image__wrapper li {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}

.profile-image__wrapper li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.profile-image__wrapper img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="profile-image__wrapper">
  <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e4/03/de/e403de788507db2505774f48f70a8eab.png"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e4/03/de/e403de788507db2505774f48f70a8eab.png"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e4/03/de/e403de788507db2505774f48f70a8eab.png"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e4/03/de/e403de788507db2505774f48f70a8eab.png"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e4/03/de/e403de788507db2505774f48f70a8eab.png"></li>
</ul>
```